# "Load" a service in an external file into a controller

Tags: angularjs

How do you "load"/"import"/"require" a service in an external file into an angular controller?  I specifically mean reference the external file inside the controller the way I have required the controller in the component code below.

**app.js**

```
angular.module('plantsync', []);
require('./lighting-the-seeds');
```

**lighting-the-seeds/index.js**

```
angular.module('lightingTheSeeds', []);
angular.module('lightingTheSeeds').component('tickerComponent', require('./ticker.component' ));

/****Does the ref to this service need to be here?*/

angular.module('lightingTheSeeds').service('carbonCalcService', require('./carbon-calc.service'));
angular.module('plantsync',['lightingTheSeeds']);
```

**lighting-the-seeds/ticker.component.js**

```
'use strict';
var tickerComponent ={
```

/*Here I can require the controller from an external file*/

```
    controller: require('./ticker.controller'),
    templateUrl: '/wp-content/themes/project_1/ticker.html'
};

module.exports = tickerComponent;
```

**lighting-the-seeds/ticker.controller.js**

```
'use strict';
```

/*I WANT TO "require" the carbo-calc.service.js HERE instead of in index.js*/

```
tickerController.$inject = ['$scope', 'carbonCalcService'];
function tickerController($scope, carboncalc) {
    $scope.carboncalc = carboncalc;
    //primitives pass by value, objects by reference!! remember!!
    $scope.carbonAvoided = {'carbon':0 };
    $scope.carboncalc.loadAppliances($scope.carbonAvoided);
    $scope.carboncalc.updateCarbon($scope.carbonAvoided);
}
module.exports = tickerController;
```

Comment: So what I want to do is: tickerController.$inject = ['$scope', require('./carbon-calc.service')];

Answer (score 0):

This

```
angular.module('lightingTheSeeds').service('carbonCalcService', require('./carbon-calc.service'));
```

Can go at the top of the controller file.

Now wasn't that easy.

Move along... these aren't the droids...